# Numpy Error in Sublime 3 with Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and have Anaconda package, so numpy should be available. But it keeps showing error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: are you trying to run python code in Sublime? If so, installing anaconda is not enough, you need to tell Sublime where the interpreter is.

Comment: @alfonso.kim Yeah I am running python code in sublime. How do I tell Sublime where the interpreter is?

Comment: @alfonso.kim are you still there maybe?